# Where does $b^2 = a^2 - c^2$ come from in derivation of the standard equation of an ellipse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

At the level of precalculus, there's a certain derivation of the equation of an ellipse that follows the same path. See [this](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~amanita/math259/handouts/m259_w09_handout1.pdf) for example.

Inevitably at one point in the derivation there's this substitution, with no explanation given:

$b^2 = a^2 - c^2$

where $a$ is the length of a major axis, $b$ is the length of a minor axis, and $c$ is the length from center to focus.

How is that equation possible? It doesn't seem to make sense from just looking at the ellipse.

Comment: The sum of the lengths is $2a$, just because an endpoint of the major axis is on the ellipse; because an endpoint of the minor axis is on the ellipse, Pythagorean theorem says $a^2=b^2+c^2$.

Comment: It's a **definition**. The handout that you linked to says "Setting $b^2 = a^2 - c^2...$"

Comment: @user296602 my question is *where* that definition came from. See  the selected answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a vertex of the ellipse on the $y$ axis. For this point the distance from  the origin of the axis is $b$, the distance from a focus is $a$ (by simmetry and noting, using the vertex on the $x$ axis, that the sum of the distances of a point from the two foci is $2a$) and the distance of the focus from the origin is $c$, and $b$ , $c$ are sides of a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse $a$.

You can see this image from [here.](https://math.tutorvista.com/geometry/major-axis-of-ellipse.html)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Draw a right triangle from $(0,0)$ to $(c,0)$ to $(0,b)$.  The pythagorean theorem tells us that $h^2 = b^2 + c^2$ where $h$, the hypotenuse, is the distance from $(c,0)$ to $(0,b)$. [Which by the distance formula is $\sqrt {(c-0)^2 + (0-b)^2} = \sqrt {c^2 + b^2}$.  But that is redundant because the distance formula *IS* the pythagorean theorem.]

Likewise the right triangle from $(0,0)$ to $(-c,0)$ to $(0,b)$ has the same hypotenuse.

Because this is an ellipse $h + h = 2h =D$, some constant.

Now consider the distance from $(c,0)$ to $(a,0)$.  This is $d_1 = a-c$.  And consider the distance from $(c,0)$ to $(-a,0)$.  This is $c + a$.

Because the is an ellipse $(a-c) + (c + a) = 2a = D = 2h$.

So $a = h$.

And $a^2 = c^2 + b^2$.

Or $c^2 = a^2 - b^2$.